# pymongo client does not connect over ssh tunnel

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pymongo

From my local machine, i have a ssh tunnel set up

```
ssh -i "mykey.pem" -L 27017:mymongo.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ec2-user@<ec2_ip> -N
```

which then, i can connect to mongo from my local machine fine via mongo shell

```
mongo --ssl --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --username <user> --password <password>
```

but

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:27017/?ssl=true', tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True, tlsCAFile='rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem')
db = client.testdb
print(db.list_collection_names())
```

but I am getting a timeout error for my aws mongo

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Could not reach any servers in [('mymongo.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com', 27017)]. Replica set is configured with internal hostnames or IPs?, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 63f876f1363f3ba7754c885sada, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mymongo.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('mymongo.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017: timed out')>]>
```

Not sure why it works with mongo shell but not with pymongo

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add `directConnection=True` parameter and that should do it.

```py
client = MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:27017/?ssl=true', tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True, tlsCAFile='rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem', directConnection=True)
```

see more: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common-issues.html?highlight=tunnel#timeout-when-accessing-mongodb-from-pymongo-with-tunneling